# Plot rollapply with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help. I want to plot a barplot with the package ggplot that represents the rollapply(vector, 2, FUN= "mean"). I want that the plot looks like this:

[image]

But the bars have to represent the "rollmeans". The code that I have used for do this plot is:

```
    ggplot(bp12.0.5op, 
       aes(fecha,part.0.5))+
  geom_point(na.rm=TRUE, color="firebrick")+
  geom_line(color="firebrick", size=1)+
  stat_summary_bin(fun.y="mean", geom="bar")+
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, linetype = 1, color = "black", size = 1 )+  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 15000000)+
  annotate("text", min(bp12.0.5op$fecha), 15500000, label = "Límite")+
  ggtitle("PARTÍCULAS DE 0,5micras EN SALA LLENADO BP12 OPERATIONAL")
  geom_line(rollapply(bp12.0.5op, width = 10, FUN = mean), col = 'red')
```

Thanks!

Comment: It will be  easier to calculate the mean in your data frame, store it as a column, and then use `geom_bar`.

Comment: I have store the mean as a column called "media", Can you help me how to use the geom_bar? thank you.

Comment: This is a different question; one which probably has an answer either by searching SO or in the ggplot documentation.